# Creating a background image with Photoshop for Unity

Tags: unity, textures, sprites

I'm making a home screen for my game. I don't know how to transfer a 2d image from Photoshop into a game that's on Unity. How do I import the image and make it visible in game? It’s a 3D game. I don't know what other information is relevant.

Comment: [Typing "Unity background image" into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unity+background+image&ia=web) turns up a full page of tutorials and Q&A about how to do this. What have you tried based on your research so far? What went wrong or didn't work the way you expected?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways of using a bitmap image as a backdrop in Unity, but the most straightforward way is to use the Unity UI system with an `Image` component.

1. Add a Canvas to your scene (GameObject -> UI -> Canvas). This will also add an EventSystem game object to your scene's hierarchy:

[image: Heirarchy with Canvas & EventSystem]

2. Add an Image as a child of your Canvas (GameObject -> UI -> Image):

[image: Heirarchy with Image]

3. Adjust the image to fill the entire screen, by setting the image's `RectTransform` component Anchor Preset to *stretch/stretch*, and setting the Left, Right, Top and Bottom to zero.

[image: Image settings in inspector]

4. Import your background image from Photoshop (or any other image editing program) into your Unity project. Unity supports many different filetypes, including Photoshop native (.psd) but also .png, .jpg, .tif, .tga and on and on. Pro tip: Layered .psds imported into Unity remain fully editable as such in Photoshop.

To use a texture as an Image component source image, its Texture Type must be set to *Sprite (2D and UI)* in import settings.

[image: import settings for UI Image]

5. Set the Source Image field of the Image component in your Canvas to this newly created sprite:

[image: Image complete]

Violá:

[image: Viola. And Oboe.]